# Get Prefab Asset From Gameobject in Edit Mode

Tags: unity

I want to get a **prefab asset** (that resides in **Project Window**) and assign it to a field like the one you get when you manually drag the prefab asset from **Project Window** to GameObject field:

[image]

But when I try to do the same thing in code (and in Edit Mode) with this function:

```
GameObject prefab_instance = PrefabUtility.GetNearestPrefabInstanceRoot(gameobj) as GameObject;
```

I get a **prefab instance** but not a **prefab asset**:

[image] [image]

How do I get a reference to **prefab asset** from the gameobject that was created from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, then I think you want to use PrefabUtility.[GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot.html) in combination with AssetDatabase.[LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html).

Like so:

```
string path = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(gameobj);
GameObject go = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(path);
Debug.Log(go.name, go);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find prefab variant of an instance you should use

```
PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(YourPrefabInstance)
```

If you want  to find orginal prefab of an instance you should use

```
PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource(YourPrefabInstance)
```

It will work only in Editor mode.